# Can't retrieve a picture to swift from parse.com using their documentation

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have been trying to follow parse.com's intruction to retrieve a picture I already successfully uploaded (also using their documentation). My code:

```
    let testObject = PFObject(className: "TestObject")
    let file = testObject["SampleImage.png"] as PFFile
    file.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if let imageData = imageData {
                let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                self.mainImg.image = image
                print("Image Retreived")
```

I am getting the error:

> "AnyObject! is not convertible to 'PFFile'"

and then it sugests that I include a ! in 'as'. However, when I do, the application runs but does not retrieve anything.

I realize this question is posted elsewhere, but the answer is not working for me. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
let testObject = PFObject(className: "TestObject")
```

This is a new empty object which isn't backed by anything on the server. You need to set the id to a known value and refresh the instance of you need to run a query to find an object before the resulting object will contain anything.

Comment: Would you mind directing me to the proper code to query the object, and then downloading it to my app?

Comment: Have you looked at fetching / querying docs on the parse site? They have sample code

Comment: I have, but Im teaching myself programming and parse is getting a little complex for me!

Comment: Start with a simple query to get all test objects. Then start to look at adding filter clauses. https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries